# Optimizacion de codigo con varias funciones try catch

Tags: javascript, npm

Tengo una duda respecto a como deberia de estar acomodado el codigo de forma profesional, la pregunta la hago debido a que siento que en las funciones estoy repitiendo mucho el try catch y siento que la estructura base es muy simple en cada funcion pero no se si esto es lo correcto o existe una forma mas limpia/profesional de hacer dicho codigo.

Si es necesario acomodarlo en diversos archivos e incluso carpetas seria de mucha ayuda que me lo mencionaran.

```
const axios = require('axios')

const url = 'http://localhost:59692/'

async function getAllAppointments() {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${url}Appointments`)
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

async function getOfficeAppintments(idoffice) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(
            `${url}Appointments/OfficeLogin?idoffice=${idoffice}`
        )
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

async function postAppointment(object) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${url}Appointmets`, object)
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

async function putAppointment(id) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${url}Appointmets/${id}`, object)
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

async function getInfoQuote(quoteNumber) {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${url}ITC/Quote/${quoteNumber}`)
        return res
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getAllAppointments,
    getOfficeAppintments,
    postAppointment,
    putAppointment,
    getInfoQuote,
}
```

Comment: A mi me parece basada en opiniones, esperemos lo que digan los demás

Comment: Coincido con @Aprendiz, y añado como opinión que el tener un try catch por función no me parece raro. Lo que si que me parece raro es que en el catch devuelvas el error con return en vez de con throw. Las funciones que llamen a éstas podrían recibir o el valor esperado si todo va bien, o un objeto de error, que seguramente no van a saber tratar, y estarías generando nuevos errores en cadena.

Comment: @ordago buen consejo gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo haría algo así:

```
async function GetInfo(variable){
 try {
        const res = await axios.get(variable)
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}

async function PutInfo(variable){
 try {
        const res = await axios.put(variable)
        return res;
    } catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

y luego llamaría a cada función reconstruyendo variable

Comment: Pero la estructura try catch de la que el habla sigues poniéndola

Comment: Sí, pero se ha reducido de 5 a 2, con lo cual es más fácil de mantener.